# PIL font size not changing

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am setting up a program to write some numbers on an image. The font size will change based on where it's writing (this size will be hardcoded).

After reading the docs, i am using `ImageFont.truetype('font.ttf', fontSize)` to load my font, with `fontSize = 400`.

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

image = Image.open('base.jpg')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image);
fontSize = 400
font = ImageFont.truetype('font.ttf', fontSize)

color = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'

def drawInfo():
    draw.text((50, 200), '20', fill=color, font=font)
    image.save('newVersion.jpg')

drawInfo()
```

Font: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Kalam?selection.family=Kalam

`base.jpg` : https://ibb.co/6XQbxHv

`newVersion.jpg` : https://ibb.co/7XFRTyg

The expected result would be that the little `20` in the top left corner under strength will be huge (with the font size being 400). Unfortunately, it seems to just be the default size. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 400 is a really big font size for PIL. Just checked some of my past code and I was using 75 and it took up a giant amount of space on a pic with similar resolution.

Comment: That fixed it, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that 400 was too big a number, but if you are *wondering why it then  caused your font to become the default size*, I will take you through a short journey.

Firstly, in your code, you use  `font = ImageFont.truetype('font.ttf', 400)`. This deploys the `truetype` function in the [ImageFont](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/src/PIL/ImageFont.py) library, which calls `FreeTypeFont`:

```
    def freetype(font):
        return FreeTypeFont(font, size, index, encoding, layout_engine)

    try:
        return freetype(font)
    except IOError:
```

The interesting part is what happens in `FreeTypeFont`, as below:

[image]

The FreeTypeFont calls core.getfont, which actually uses the [_imagingft.c](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/src/_imagingft.c) library, and 
this is where the font size of 400 killed the _imagingft getfont function, which gave up loading the text and threw an error:

[image]

Finally, if you remember the first function, `truetype`, it actually has a `try: except IOError:`, which causes it to call the `FreeTypeFont` function with *no font size*, making it default to 10, and causing your current issue:

[image]

Essentially, the solution is to try the maximum font size that will not break the _imagingft library, or to make use of a different library to load the fonts.

Answer (score 1):

400 was most likely too big a number, after reducing it to 75 it worked fine.